# SQL Query for Search & Replace(Need to update) the whole database if matched the string in phpMyAdmin/MySQL - wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Currently i have the links look like as http://example.com, http://example.com/images, http://example.com/posts/..., http://example.com/links/... about 3000+ matched on the database need to be updated with "https" like as 
https://example.com, https://example.com/images, https://example.com/posts/..., https://example.com/links/...

Where i have already updated the wp site url http://example.com to https://example.com therefore, there are 3000+ available in the DB.

Is there a easy way to make that or something in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, change table_name & field as per your requirement.

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = replace(field,'http','https');

UPDATE table_name SET field = replace(field,'[string-to-find]','[string-that-will-replace-it]');
```

**NB:** But Before you do that, you should definitely do a database dump or whatever you use for backups.More about [Mysql Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p databasename > my_sql_dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But i have done it through a search & replace wordpress plugin.